# Visual selection responses with Google Assistant, List not working?

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

I have all the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-selection) (the List section) copied into my code to try to form a visual list in my assistant conversation.

The error I am getting back is "Your action is not responding right now. Please try again soon" . There is no other error showing in my logs, my logs seem to think that my action was successful.

I have deduced that the error in my code is from this section:

```js
  conv.add(new List({
    title: 'List title',
    subtitle: 'List subtitle',
    items: [
      {
        key: 'ITEM_1'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_2'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_3'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_4'
      }
    ],
  }));
```

I am unable to figure out where the error is originally from though. I have List included from my required section from '@assistant/conversation'.

Does anyone have the docs for Lists or a solution to this so I am able to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Actions Console simulator from that response?

Comment: @NickFelker No I do not

Comment: Can you provide the entire intent handler that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The keys provided in the List payload correspond to names of a type entries.

Please ensure you are defining the type entries in the same turn of conversation that you are sending the List response, as seen in the [documentation you linked](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-selection#ListSamples).

Also ensure you have defined the Type you are overriding within Actions Builder.

For example the snippet in the documentation expects a Type with the name `prompt_option` to be created in your Actions Builder project before overriding it.